Adding fontSizes in Wordpress Editor
I am working with a custom theme and in the WP editor the only typography size available is "S"

I am trying to add a Medium Size to the block Button with this theme.json
{ "version": 2, "settings": { "blocks": { "core/button": { "typography": { "fontSizes": [ { "slug": "small", "size": "1rem", "name": "Small" }, { "slug": "medium", "size": "1.5rem", "name": "Medium" } ] } } } } }
Then I see in editor the two sizes but all the layout of the full post are gone margins, font-family, etc.
And the changes of size are not reflected in frontend event the font-size of the button shows as
has-medium-font-size { font-size: var(--wp--preset--font-size--medium) !important; }
I have the feeling I am missing a few things. Any help would be great appreciated.
Thanks!

I kind of found a solution. Instead of using theme.json I added this:
 add_theme_support(
    'editor-font-sizes',
    array(
        array(
            'name'      => __('Extra Small'),
            'shortName' => __('XS'),
            'size'      => 12.8,
            'slug'      => 'extrasmall'
        ),
        array(
            'name'      => __('Small'),
            'shortName' => __('S'),
            'size'      => 16,
            'slug'      => 'small'
        ),
        array(
            'name'      => __('Medium'),
            'shortName' => __('M',
            'size'      => 18,
            'slug'      => 'medium'
        ),
        array(
            'name'      => __('Large'),
            'shortName' => __('L'),
            'size'      => 24,
            'slug'      => 'large'
        )
    )
);

